# In React Native I could not Import List but I can successfully use ListItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Doing a project for simple FlatList i imported
 `npm i react-native-elements --save`

npm i --save react-native-vector-icons

then i linked it

react-native link react-native-vector-icons

[when I try to add List in importing react-native-elements can't get suggestions and can't resolve image can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70rqO.png)

Code for App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, FlatList, View} from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';


export default class App extends Component {

  state={
      data: []
    };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=10');
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({data: json.results});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <ScrollView>
        <List>
            <FlatList
                  data={this.state.data}
                  keyExtractor={(x,i) => i}
                  renderItem={({item}) =>
                      <ListItem
                          roundAvatar
                          avatar={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}}
                          title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
                      />
                  }
              />
          </List>
          </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Code for index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

[The error I received when Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0DJb.png)

Comment: Did you restart the packager after linking?

Comment: yes i restarted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: There is no `List` component  available in [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements#components-included), that's why you can't import it.

Just remove the import and also the List element in your render function and it should work.

Edit: 
Since version [v1.0.0-beta4](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta4) the `List` component is removed.

If you still want to have the `List` you can install any version below 1.0.0-beta4 with the following command:

```
npm install --save react-native-elements@1.0.0-beta3
```

Replace `@1.0.0-beta3` with any version you want. You can find all available versions under the tab "Versions" [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-elements).

Comment: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/lists.html how they imported List from react-native-elements

Comment: @TharunEniyan They are using an older version of `react-native-elements`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding somthing to @TimH answer.

RN element is actually in the `1.1.0` version, wich doesn't includes the `List` component anymore.

Here's [the documentation for this version 1.1.0](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html)

The version `0.19.x` is an old one and the `List` component was still here. Your are reading the `0.19.1` documentation while the `1.1.0` is probably installed in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It inspired me to update mine a litte bit. +1